# Catch a crash on Windows CE

Tags: c++, exception, windows-ce

I would like to achieve the following but after days of trial I still could not figure it out.
I am developing an application in C++ for **Windows CE 5.0** and I would like to be able to dump a callstack to a file when it crashes (programmatically). I already know how to get the callstack itself, the problem is that I don't know how to **run my own code when a crash occurs**.
I tried placing my code into catch blocks but the stack is already unwound there so no luck. Some exception handler functions are available on the platform but set_terminate() or set_unexpected() do not catch all types of exceptions.
The application is single threaded and uses Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2.

Comment: I'm using VS2009 and the compiler which came with the SDK.

Comment: Firstly, I have no experience with CE or VS2009 (have only heard of VS2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010). If VS2009 is similar to any of these you probably need to enable structured exception handling to catch the exceptions you are wanting to. To enable structured exception handling you need to specify the compiler switch [/EHa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I meant VS2008 that is version 9. I have researched SEH but I can't see how that would help me with this.

Comment: _set_se_translator would be a solution but that isn't available on WinCE.

Comment: I thought it would have helped as you stated you placed your code in catch blocks? The SEH try/catch construct is slight different from the normal try/catch: `__try { char* p = 0; if (*p = 'a') {} } _except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) { std::cout << GetExceptionCode() << "\n"; }`

Comment: Also, you could do this at expense of not being able to determine the structured exception code: `try { char* p = 0; if (*p = 'a') {} } catch (...) { std::cout << "Error\n"; }`

Comment: In catch blocks I'm not able to dump the stack where the exception happened, because when execution reaches the catch block, the stack is unwound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried SEH?

```
__try {
// stuff
} __except (DecideWhatToDo()) {

}

int DecideWhatToDo(void){
  // Stack analysis here, should work with \EHsc and \EHa
  //  you could return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION here so stack should not be unwound
  return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER
}
```

Actually I have never tried it. How do you interpret your call stack? So that it is usefull to find bugs?